# Synonym request: [Age] to [Lifespan]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We have two tags for the age of pets. [age](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) and [lifespan](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifespan). It makes sense to me that [age](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) should be a synonym of [lifespan](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifespan). Could we merge them?

Answer (score 2):

Well, age is usually how much the pet has lived so far, while lifespan is the average maximum age/time the pet can reach. They kinda have different meanings

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, I see this is your first Meta post and that you are rather new to Stack Exchange.  Negative votes here don't have the same meaning on Meta as they do on the main site. [Voting is different on meta](http://pets.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not synonyms. I suggest keeping [lifespan](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifespan) but blacklisting [age](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) in favour of more specific tags.

As Hussein said in another answer, questions about lifespan are clearly about the life expectancy of a given species or breed. However, age has no clear meaning on its own; it could refer to a young pet, or a very old one, or a request for age identification, or a question about normal development.

---

### Life Expectancy

These should be retagged with [lifespan](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifespan)

- [What is the life expectancy of a Mustache Parakeet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19141/what-is-the-life-expectancy-of-a-mustache-parakeet)

### Physical, social, and emotional development

These deserve a brand new tag, [development](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development)

- [Cat weight guide for Russian Blue](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28593/cat-weight-guide-for-russian-blue)
- [Is my pet tortoise's size normal for his age?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17746/is-my-pet-tortoises-size-normal-for-his-age) (actually about development)
- [When is the best age to get a baby parrot?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11850/when-is-the-best-age-to-get-a-baby-parrot)
- [How old should bearded dragons be when you adopt them?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5513/how-old-should-bearded-dragons-be-when-you-adopt-them)

### Age Identification

Maybe keep [age](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) just for this, or replace it with something like [how-old](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-old)

- [How old is my kitten?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20095/how-old-is-my-kitten) (perhaps the only case where [age](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age) is appropriate?)
- [How do I determine if this rodent is an adult or baby?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18523/how-do-i-determine-if-this-rodent-is-an-adult-or-baby)
- [We found a dove. How do we care for it?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26194/we-found-a-dove-how-do-we-care-for-it)

### Stages of life

It is probably worthwhile to create tags for distinct stages of life. These tags, when combined with species/breed tags, really help to select an area of expertise with RSS feeds and/or custom filters.

#### Young

Add [junior-pets](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junior-pets) to these questions.

- [Another New Turtle](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/29004/another-new-turtle) (request for sex identification)

#### Middle age

- [Is my cat healthy, ill, or just getting older?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/25570/is-my-cat-healthy-ill-or-just-getting-older)
- [At what age do ginger cats start having black whiskers?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20956/at-what-age-do-ginger-cats-start-having-black-whiskers) (actually a question about development)

#### Senior

Add [senior-pet](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senior-pet) to these questions.

- [Should I carry my elderly cocker spaniel out of the car?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/24263/should-i-carry-my-elderly-cocker-spaniel-out-of-the-car)
- [My dog is old and dying, how do I convince him not to be scared of me?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21287/my-dog-is-old-and-dying-how-do-i-convince-him-not-to-be-scared-of-me)
- [My German Shepherd has arthritis, how can I get her down the steps?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20982/my-german-shepherd-has-arthritis-how-can-i-get-her-down-the-steps)